# Google Maps can't get GPS location on Android 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-mapview

My Device gps found satellite but doesn't lock. It keeps constantly trying to acquire the GPS signal, but most times it fails. I tested it on other android version 4.1.1 and the problem persists.
I just tried many combinations of resetting both Google location services and the location access and nothing fixes it. I go into maps and I can't get a gps lock at all. I've noticed, it takes longer to get a GPS signal, and the signal gays lost more often
Disabling the 'Google location services' also doesn't work

In every app that uses GPS only the empty circle shows up. Sometimes (after many seconds) the dot appears and starts blinking. But even after three minutes my phone is searching for a GPS signal.

On official google map app, It say searching for GPS signal and stays like that

I don't have any bug report.It just looking for satellites all the time,  in some point there is only circle without the dot inside.

### sample code used to get GPS coordinates

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      locationManager = (LocationManager)                               getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    c.setBearingRequired(true);
    pro = locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(pro, 0, 0, this);
    Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(pro);
    gpsManager = new GPSManager();
    if (loc != null) {
        showLocation(loc);
    } 


    @Override
protected void onPause() {


    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool for debugging GPS issues is the GPS Test app. It shows you how many satellites your phone is detecting, how strong their signal is, how accurate the fix is, etc. This at least lets you rule out if you're in an area with bad satellite coverage.

I've only got one app on the market, but it is a GPS based app. Here's some of my code that got things working. Mind you, this only uses the GPS, it doesn't do rough location based on network.

```
public void initLocationManager()
{
    myGpsManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    long time = 0;
    float dist =0;
    myGpsListener = new locationListener();
    myGpsManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", time, dist, myGpsListener);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    myGpsManager.removeUpdates(myGpsListener);
    super.onPause();
}
```